# Scala adding methods with complex types to final classes

Tags: scala, vector, types

I'm trying to add a dot product method to the `Vector` class. I tried something like:

```
class MatrixVector[T <: Numeric[T]] extends Vector[T]{

  def dot(vector: MatrixVector[T]): T = {
    this.zip(vector).map(t =>  t._1 + t._2).sum
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work because `Vector` is final and cant be extended. The purported solution to extending final classes is to create an implicit class. However, this doesn't work because I want the vectors to work for all `Numeric` types, and I cant create an implicit class that passes a  type constraint. E.g.:

```
object {
  implicit class dotProd[T <: Numeric[T]](v1: Vector[T]) {
    def dot(v2: Vector[T]): T = {
      v1.zip(v2).map(t =>  t._1 + t._2).sum
    }
  }
}
```

This results in a type error, and I'm not even sure it makes sense have a type constraint with an implicit class.

How can I extend a final class with methods that have complex types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> implicit class dotProd[T](v1: Vector[T])(implicit ev:Numeric[T]) { 
  def dot(v2: Vector[T]): T = v1.zip(v2).map(t => ev.times(t._1, t._2) ).sum // see (*) at the bottom
}
defined class dotProd

scala> Vector(1,2,3).dot(Vector(10,10,10))
res0: Int = 60
```

Numeric is not a class that is extended by numeric types. [Numeric](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) is a *type class*. One example instance of Numeric is [IntIsIntegral](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric$$IntIsIntegral$.html), this class doesn't represent an Int but the numeric operations one can perform over Ints.

(*) Btw, your original definition of [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) was adding the elements of the vectors, which is not a correct dot product.